# Javascript : HTML5 Canvas and id loop with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getelementbyid

I'm pretty new with Javascript and I would like to use canvas with javascript in my Django template.

I have a little html part and javascript part which looks like this :

```
{% for document in publication.documents.all %}
<td class="col-md-1">
    <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</td>
{% endfor %}

<script>
  pdfjsLib.getDocument('http://localhost:8000/media/media/loremipsum2.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
    console.log("pdf loaded");
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
        var scale = 0.40;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I'm trying to use `PDF.js` in order to make some things. In my javascript code, I would like to handle `getElementById` in order to loop over dynamical html canvas id.

So I have this code now :

```
{% for document in publication.documents.all %}
<td class="col-md-1">
    <canvas id="the-canvas{{document.id}}"></canvas>
</td>
{% endfor %}

<script>
  pdfjsLib.getDocument('http://localhost:8000/media/media/loremipsum2.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
    console.log("pdf loaded");
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
        var scale = 0.40;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas{{document.id}}');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The first code displays only the first canvas object (it's normal). The second one should display each canvas object but it doesn't work. It displays nothing.

Did I make any mistake in my javascript code ?

Thank you

***Edit :***

Code with loop over tag `<canvas>` :

```
{% for document in publication.documents.all %}
<td class="col-md-1">
    <canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>
</td>
{% endfor %}

<script>
  pdfjsLib.getDocument('http://localhost:8000/media/media/loremipsum2.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
    console.log("pdf loaded");
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
        var scale = 0.40;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;

        var renderContext = {
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport
        };
        page.render(renderContext);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` will return only single object because there should be only one element with single id on the html page. You can use `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')` or give class to canvas and use `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')`

Comment: @ArunKumar That's why my id is dynamical with django variable inside. It's never the same id.

Comment: It will still return single object. You have to use either tag or class to retrieve list

Comment: Doesn't work with tag or class

Comment: can you share your code that you've used for tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did I get this right you want to loop over multiple canvases? As the question was not tagged `Django` I have no idea what that "dynamic variable" stuff is :D. But maybe that block of code helps you:

You should be iterating over all the canvas objects returned by `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')` but you are treating it as a single object

```js
let canvases = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"));
canvases.forEach(canvas => {
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
```

In your example, it would look like:

```
pdfjsLib.getDocument('http://localhost:8000/media/media/loremipsum2.pdf').then(function (pdf) {
    console.log("pdf loaded");
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
        var scale = 0.40;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

        var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
        Array.from(canvases).forEach((canvas) => {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            var renderContext = {
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            };
            page.render(renderContext);
        });
    });
  });
```

**Edit:** you could use stuff like:

```
let can = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(<className>);
let can = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(<CSS query>);
...
```

If the right on is not in the list just ask :3

Comment: Made some edits to your answer, we also try to stay away from greetings and signatures to keep answers on point. Last suggestion, avoid writing **Edit:** and adding more stuff, just rewrite your answer and rework as necessary.

Comment: @Elias.G Yes it's exactly what I want ! I didn't think I had to loop over canvas too. Now, I just have to see how I can pass variable in place of my pdf localhost url :)

Comment: Something like this? `document.location = "<PATH TO PDFs>" + PDFname` or get the url with `document.URL`

Comment: in my template I have this variable `{{document.upload}}`, so I would like to make something like this : `pdfjsLib.getDocument('http://localhost:8000/media/'+ {{ document.upload }})`

Comment: Thank you, I have to see that ;)